# Debug Spring Boot app from Intellij where service is started in a multi service docker-compose file?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose YML file that includes multiple Spring Boot apps.
Is it possible to debug one of these Spring Boot apps from Intellij?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends how the apps are started within the Docker container. One option could be starting the application in debug mode with the following in the Dockerfile of the app you want to debug:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n -jar myApp.jar
```

Remember to build your container again and then attach a remote debugger with IntelliJ to the port 8000.